# Perform Centrality Functions on all Nodes using Cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, graph-theory, cytoscape.js, cytoscape, network-analysis

I need to calculate [degree](http://js.cytoscape.org/#eles.degreeCentrality), closeness and betweenness centrality for every node on a graph. I'm currently using the functions built into Cytoscape.js on each node after the `cy.ready()` event. However, as the graphs are quite large (250+ Nodes, 650+ Connections) it's taking too long to compute. Can anyone suggest a more efficient method?

```
var calculateSNA = function() {
  // Don't run if already set...
  if(data.sna) return false
  console.log('Running SNA')

  _.map(nodes, function(node) {
    var target = cy.nodes('#' + node.data.id)
    node.data.sna  = {
      degreeCentrality: cy.$().dc({ root: target }).degree,
      closenessCentrality: cy.$().cc({ root: target }),
      betweennessCentrality: cy.$().bc().betweenness(target)
    }
    return node
  })

  // Add SNA data to local storage
  Data.add({
    sna: true
  })
  Node.set(nodes)

  console.log('SNA complete')
}


cy.ready(function(event) {
  console.log('cy.ready()')
  calculateSNA()
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the algorithm once, rather than running it N times.  Then just query the result:

```
let ccn = cy.elements().closenessCentralityNormalized({ /* my options */ });

cy.nodes().forEach( n => {
  n.data({
    ccn: ccn.closeness( n )
  });
} );
```

Use normalised versions of centrality algorithms unless you have a good reason to do otherwise.  Only the normalised versions really mean anything if you compare results in one graph to results in another graph, for example.

Comment: How to calculate normalised indegree centrality Please guide

                                                let ccn = cy.elements().dcn({ 'options.directed':true });
                                                
                                                $scope.ndd = cy.nodes().forEach( n => {
                                                  n.data({
                                                    ccn: ccn.degree( n )
                                                  });
                                                } )

Comment: Not sure why but when I tried this for degreeCentrality, I'm getting an "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'connectedEdges' of undefined". Can anyone please explain why?