# Default options of Cytoscape centrality metrics in Cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js, cytoscape

How to get the same results for the Cytoscape normalized centrality metrics calculations in Cytoscape.js?
I am exporting from Cytoscape 3.6 a JSON containing a graph from a network and I load it into Cystoscape.js, but the metric values do not match. Just for the record, in Cytoscape.js I'm not loading the JSON with the results of the metrics already calculated, I'm loading just the nodes and edges.

I'm using the following code to calculate the metrics, available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107018/perform-centrality-functions-on-all-nodes-using-cytoscape-js).

```
let ccn = cy.elements().closenessCentralityNormalized({ /* my options */ });

cy.nodes().forEach( n => {
  n.data({
    ccn: ccn.closeness( n )
  });
} );
```

Thanks.